# Problems involve exponential equality constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming

I have a question like

Let, $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots, \mu_K),$ given $M: K \times m$ a full rank matrix

$\min_{\mu \in \mathbb R^K} \sum^n_{i=1}\sum^K_{k=1}(y_{ik} - \mu_k)^2$ subject to $\log \mu = M\beta,~\beta \in \mathbb R^m.$

The $\log$ here is an element-wise log transform of a vector.

I think this problem is a nonlinear problem due to the log constraint.

Initially, I thought a gradient descent method with a projection to the constraint set $\{\mu: \mu = \exp(M\beta), \beta \in \mathbb R^m\}$

However, this cannot guarantee a solution because it is not a convex problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is $\beta$ also part of the decision variables?

Using the constraints $\log \mu = M \beta$, you can substitute out $\mu$ in the objective, which yields an unconstrained problem

\begin{align}
    \min_{\beta} \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \left( y_{ik} - \exp(M_{k} \beta) \right)^2
\end{align}
where $M_{k}$ denotes the $k$-th row of $M$.

This is indeed a non-convex function so, in that form, unless you have few variables, it's unlikely that you'll find a global minimizer efficiently. If you're OK with local minimizers, quasi-Newton methods like L-BFGS may give you better convergence than gradient descent.

---

[Edit: $M$ has full column rank, not row rank, so the approach below does not guarantee a feasible solution]

That being said, you mention that $M$ has full rank.
Is that full row rank, i.e., does the system $M \beta = \log \mu$ always has a solution (for any choice of $\mu$)?
If that's the case, then you can solve
\begin{align}
    \min_{\mu} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \left( y_{ik} - \mu_{k} \right)^2\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \mu > 0
\end{align}
then retrieve $\beta$ by solving $M \beta = \log \mu$.
This yields a convex quadratic program, which can be solved very efficiently, followed by a linear system solve.
There is one catch: optimization solvers do not like "strictly positive" constraints. You can handle this by adding a small, positive lower bound $\mu \geq \epsilon$. If none of the lower bounds are active, you have a global minimizer. Otherwise, you have a (presumably good) solution.

Note that solving the above quadratic problem with constraints $\mu \geq 0$ instead of $\mu > 0$ will give you a valid lower bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem. You can use this to gauge the quality of the solution you obtain when solving with $\mu \geq \epsilon$.

[Edit] when $M$ does not have full row rank, one can solve the above quadratic program, obtain $\mu$, then project $\log \mu$ onto the column space of $M$ and recover a feasible $\beta$. While this always yields a feasible solution, it has no guarantee on the quality of the resulting objective objective value.

Comment: Thank you. I forget $K >m$ i.e. $M\beta$ indicates a constrained feasible set of $\mu$. and all observation $y_i$ are always positive. Then $\mu > 0$ would not be a big issue.

Comment: Do above conditions, if satisfied, allow to get a global minima of the subject function? Or can I get a solution with a projection $\log \mu$ into $M$ column space after solving the quadratic problem?

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I updated my answer